# iOS - Correct way to "listen" for a delegate method from within a class

Tags: ios, delegates, core-location, appdelegate

I've just implemented the `CLLocationManager` in my `AppDelegate`, which is currently printing the location whenever it's updated.

What I'm trying to do now is trigger a method in one of my view controllers whenever that location is updated.

I've done something similar before using `protocol`, but I'm not sure if that's possible with the `AppDelegate`.

I'm working in Swift, but an Objective-C response would also be helpful as I'm looking for the logic behind how to achieve this.

Comment: You can use notifications (google NSNotificationCenter).

Comment: You could receive the location changes in the view controller and pass the information to `AppDelegate` because `AppDelegate` is accessible from every class

Comment: Implemented the ``CLLocationManager``? Do you mean ``CLLocationManagerDelegate``? Or you just instantiated ``CLLocationManager `` and stored reference in '``AppDelegate``?

Comment: @user996142, sorry, I'm still learning at the moment. What I meant by that is that using both `CLLocationManager` and its delegate, I have the app logging location upon `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`. I figured that this would be best way (as opposed to doing it within a view controller), because it can take a few seconds to get location and my app is reliant on it. Having said that, I see that it might just be easier to do it all within the relevant view controller, as @vadian said

Answer (score 0):

You can post notifications to `NSNotificationCenter` from your application delegate (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) and subscribe to in in your controller (do not forget to unsubscribe in `dealloc`). Just make sure you do not update any GUI when application is in background (you can check state directly in controller).